# Is it possible to boot a USB without the BIOS using only Windows?

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I find myself having to boot Linux from an external flash drive quite often. This is my method of doing this:

> Restarting the computer, entering the BIOS, selecting the external
>   drive, and finally I am able to boot into the drive.

Using C, C++, or any other programming language, is it possible to have a program boot an external drive without having to manually enter the BIOS? Would I have to create some type of custom boot loader that could interact with Windows? My goal is to create a program that could boot the drive using only one click from Window.

Comment: I only had to enter the BIOS (actually UEFI now) once: to set up a boot priority. Now, if there is a bootable USB stick present at power up, it boots from there, otherwise if there is a bootable optical disk present, from there, otherwise it looks for the first bootable hard drive, where it happens that Windows will boot.

Comment: You don't need code for that. [BCDEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options) will do.